# When to retain an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, reference-counting

When an NSString object is passed in as an argument, should I always do `retain` and `release`:

```
-forExample:(NSString*)str{
    [str retain];

    //do something

    [str release];
}
```

or not? Where and when should I use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference count of that object isn't going to change over the course of this method, so there is no reason to send it `retain`. From Apple's [Memory Management essay](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) (which you should definitely look over):

> If you receive an object from elsewhere in your program, it is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method or function it was received in. If you want it to remain valid beyond that scope, you should retain or copy it. If you try to release an object that has already been deallocated, your program crashes.

You only need to retain an object when you need it to stick around past the current scope.

```
- (void) forExample: (NSString *)theString {
    // Will need this object later. Stuff it into an ivar and retain it.
    // myString = [theString retain];    
    // For NSString, it's actually better to copy, because this
    // could be a _mutable_ string, and it would in fact be best to use
    // the setter for the ivar, which should deal with the memory management:
    [self setMyString:theString];

    // Do things...

    // Don't release.
}
```

If you have retained an object, you then need to send it `release` when you no longer need it.

```
- (void) otherExample {
    [myString doYourStringThing];
    // If you don't need the string past this point (which would be slightly
    // unusual -- it leaves an ivar unset) release it and set it to nil.
    // [myString release]; myString = nil;
    // Again, it would be best to use the setter:
    [self setMyString:nil];
}

// Generally you keep ivars around until the instance is deallocated,
// and release them in dealloc
- (void) dealloc {
    [myString release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of using it (retain an object when you need it to stick around past the current scope)?

Comment: Well, generally you stick it into an ivar in that case. If you're going to increase its reference count, you also need to keep a reference to it (i.e., have a variable holding it) so that you can get at it later to use it and release it. Updated.

Comment: Now the final doubt, if `theString` param was an `autorelease` object,the `autoReleasePool` can always keep it usable when passing it to function and usable through running the function ? Thank you very much @Josh.

Comment: The autorelease pool won't be drained until control returns to the run loop. That won't happen until the end of any one call chain generated by your code. IOW, you never have to worry about the autorelease pool getting rid of an object, again, until the current scope ends.

Comment: Thank you . Maybe I can judge now .  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should never do either, because, like a good developer, you are keeping up with the latest trends in Objective-C and using [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Automatic Reference Counting removes the need to manually call retain/release, and comes with LLVM 3.0 and Xcode 4.2.

If, for some reason, you want to use manual memory management like you are doing here, you should not manually call `retain` and `release` in most cases. Usually, it is okay to use your judgement and not retain every argument individually.

The only time when this might be a good idea is if your method is, at some point, calling a callback or something that may release the argument before you get to use it. This could be the case if, for instance, your function takes a block and calls that block during its execution. If that block releases the object that was passed as an argument, and you then use that object after calling the block, the argument is essentially a dangling pointer.

**Example of such a scenario**:

```
- (void)myFunction:(NSString *)foo block:(void (^)())callback {
    [foo retain];
    callback();
    // .. do some stuff
    [foo release];
}

- (void)myCallingFunction {
    NSString * myVariable = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Test"];
    [self myFunction:myVariable block:^ {
        [myVariable release];
    }];
}
```

As you can see, the code `[myVariable release]` would be reached before the `// .. do some stuff` comment.

Comment: The point about ARC is well-taken, but your example of the block releasing the object seems pathological. The block doesn't own that reference and has no business disposing of it.

Comment: You still need to understand about retain/release because ARC is not available on every platform and most existing code does not use it.  Also ARC still uses it under the covers so you have to understand about retain (strong) cycles.  Finally, in your example the block violates the memory management rules.

Comment: Yes, in this case it is obvious that the block is violating a rule, but in some other cases the block would, for instance, set a property to `nil`, or some such thing that could cause a problem.